# Run the constructor of a WCF as soon as IIS is restarted

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I am using Quartz.Net (I am initializing it through the constructor) to schedule some tasks but I'm dealing with a problem. A WCF service is hosted in IIS and I want as soon as the IIS is restarted the constructor of my service to start and initialize the scheduler.

Atm I have to call a dummy method so I can start my service running. I played a bit with IIS and some settings I found but none have worked.

Comment: Sounds like a poor separation of concerns (using service ctor to setup scheduled events). I would consider breaking that off, and if it's in IIS consider using WebActivatorEx.

Comment: Hey @BradChristie I'm open to new solutions and I'll give WebActivatorEx a try! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Auto Start** feature of **Application Fabric**, as your service is hosted in IIS.

If you don't have AppFabric installed, install first.

Open IIS manager, select your WCF application then click "Configuration" in "Manage WCF and WF Services".
Choose "Auto-Start" and enable the feature.

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx

[**UPDATED**] As Ahmed ilyas said, AppFabric can be discontinued, so you can also use the Application Initialization. Read more here:
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Hope it helps.

Comment: Be aware that AppFabric is no longer supported. There is extended support but no new development will be continued on the product.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas yes, good point. You can use the Application Initialization feature, I'll include this in my answer.

Comment: Thank you people!! I'll try this tomorrow and come back to mark your answer!! :) I see that "Application Initialization" is for IIS 8 but my computers run the older 7 version. Perhaps AppFabric is more appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

> Run the constructor of a WCF as soon as IIS is restarted?

By default your service hosted in IIS doesn't activate automatically by itself not unless consumed first.

I think you need some restructuring in your implementation. Like hosting your service in Windows Service or separate your initialization of schedule in service constructor.

Comment: you don't need neither to create a Windows Service nor restructure your code, IIS provide this feature, read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx